# Posting user entered text using $.ajax, how to pass text content in the data property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What options do I have for passing large text in a call to `$.ajax(...)`?

I have the content stored in a variable already:

```
articleText
```

So I have:

```
$.ajax(
 type: "POST",
 url: "/test/add_article",
 dataType: "json",
 data: ??????,
 success: function(d) {
    alert(d);
 }
});
```

In the docs they show:

```
"p1=asdfasdf&p2=2sdfasdf"
```

Also:

```
data: ({someName: someValue })
```

I like the latter, so is the `someValue` where I put my variable?

What about encoding it or is it just like a form post where I can handle that on the server-side?

)

Comment: Have you tried it?  I learned jquery yesterday. (Literally) and figured it out by breaking it until it worked...

Comment: yes, I just want to know my options....I've done the 1st method

Comment: The first method is already a query string whereas the second method will be converted to query string by jQuery unless `processData` is explicitly set to `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would simply do `data: { aT: articleText }`. Then in your server-side script you can access that text as post variable `aT`...in PHP it would be: `$_POST['aT']`.

jQuery converts `{ aT: articleText }` to `"aT=myTextContentWouldBeHere"`.

Answer (score 2):

Just change `data` to

```
data: {"someName": someValue}
```

if someValue is a variable, else

```
data: {"someName": "someValue"}
```

if someValue itself is the value.